# I want to keep '/' changes

Tags: systemback

I'm using systemback for creating a live system for copying my os to another machine easily, but the file copied to '/' directory is not coming in live image. Please anyone have some insight regarding this or can recommend any other application like systemback which can work for my situation.

Comment: Please provide some more detail on the software ("systemback") and what you ultimatelly want to achieve. Provide Ubuntu version as well, because that may matter sometimes.

Comment: Ubuntu version 20.04 LTS, I want to create bootable live image of my running OS with all user changes, Systemback is a good software for this but it only copies standard linux file system and any other file copied by user in root directory is not copied in made image. I want to keep a file at root directory copied by me thats all.

Comment: Please add any information that may be relevant to solve the problem to your question: use "edit". Comments may not be read, may not be displayed, or may disappear.